# Generic C# Class: Set "Generic" Property

Tags: c#, types, generics

I'm quite new to C#, so I might have a problem that C# has a simple solution for. I have a generic class with a property of "generic" type. I want to have a function to set that property, but I need to convert it to do so.

```
public class BIWebServiceResult<T>
{
    public T Data;

    public delegate StatusCode StringToStatusCode(string Input);

    public void SetData(string Input, StringToStatusCode StringToError)
    {
        if (StringToError(Input) == 0)
        {
            if (Data is string[])
            {
                Data = new string[1];
                Data[0] = Input;
            }
            else if (Data is string)
            {
                Data = Input;
            }
            else if (Data is bool)
            {
                Data = DetectBool(Input);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool DetectBool(string Compare)
    {
        return Compare == "true";
    }
}
```

The problem with that approach is, that it does not work :)

(No that's not all code, just a snippet to show what my problem is)

It doesn't even compile, because "Data = new string[]" can't work if Data is - for example - boolean.

How do I implement a function that behaves differently depending on the type of my generic property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a generic class, but you're changing its behavior based on its generic type argument.

Since this behavior is specialized according to `T`, you should really make your generic class an abstract base from which to derive specialized subclasses:

```
public abstract class BIWebServiceResult<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public delegate StatusCode StringToStatusCode(string Input);

    public abstract void SetData(string Input, StringToStatusCode StringToError);
}
```

Then you might have, for example:

```
public class BIWebServiceStrArrayResult : BIWebServiceResult<string[]>
{
    public override void SetData(string Input, StringToStatusCode StringToError)
    {
        if (StringToError(Input) == 0)
        {
            Data = new string[1];
            Data[0] = Input;
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, though, I'd be inclined to do away with all this manual string manipulation altogether and leave the job of parsing input to whatever code is calling this method:

```
// This is the same signature used by, e.g., int.TryParse, double.TryParse, etc.
public delegate bool Parser<T>(string input, out T output);

public void SetData(string Input, Parser<T> parser)
{
    T value;
    if (parser(Input, out value))
        Data = value;
}
```

By the way, typically it's not really necessary to define your own delegates when the same signature is already available in the form of an `Action`* or `Func`*. In the case of your `StringToStatusCode`, this could simply be defined as a `Func<string, StatusCode>`. (But I would still personally recommend something like the last bit of code I posted instead.)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the [`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method:

```
Convert.ChangeType( input, typeof(T) );
```

but this will only work for the types that the `Convert` class is aware of. Conversions to most custom types just will fail with a `InvalidCastException`.

**As a general pratice, this is not a good way to structure a generic class.** Generics are meant to unify types based on a *common interface*. In your case, that common interface is that you expect a conversion from a string representation to the generic type.

If you really need to support conversion of arbitrary input from `string` to some type `T` you should provide a separate generic function as a parameter to the type that can perform the conversion. Here's an example:

```
class BIWebServiceResult<T>
{
    private readonly Func<string,T> m_ValueParser;  

    public BIWebServiceResult( Func<string,T> valueParser )
    {
        m_ValueParser = valueParser;
    }

    public void SetData(string Input, StringToStatusCode StringToError) 
    {
        Data = m_ValueParser( Input );   // use supplied conversion func
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach that will work for simple types is to use a TypeConverter.

```
T value = default(T);
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
if (converter != null)
{
    if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))
    {
        value = (T)converter.ConvertFrom(myString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say if this would make much sense in your scenario, but you could perhaps use a child class for each of the possible data types, somewhat like:

```
public abstract class BIWebServiceResult<T>
    {
        public T Data;

        public delegate void StringToStatusCode(string Input);

        public abstract void SetData(string Input, StringToStatusCode StringToError);
    }


    public class StringBIServiceResult : BIWebServiceResult<string[]>
    {
        public override void SetData(string Input, StringToStatusCode StringToError)
        {

                Data = new string[1];
                Data[0] = Input;
        }

        private bool DetectBool(string Compare)
        {
            return Compare == "true";
        }
    }
```

this would avoid the casting and using type converters, but might be make your class inheritance chain unduly complex...

Comment: Sorry, Dan Tao was just a few seconds faster with the same answer, but thanks for your answer! :)